# Angular component is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9, angular-components, angular-upgrade

I have recently upgraded my angular project from angular 8 to angular 9, when I try to run serve command I am getting below error.

```
error NG8001: 'app-abcd-breadcrumb' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-abcd-breadcrumb' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

2. If 'app-abcd-breadcrumb' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.


 error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

5 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Can anyone please help me on this ? these components are the components created by me for the project. it is not any library component

Comment: your components should be declared in the correct modules. Check that parent component where `<app-abcd-breadcrumbs>` is used and the breacrumbs itself are visible to each other from modules perspective

Comment: Did you visit this page? https://angular.io/errors/NG8001

Comment: 1. `AppAbcdComponent` should be declared in an appropriate NgModule (#1) and exported.
2. The `AppAbcdHolderComponent` (or whatever name it has) is declared in a different NgModule (#2). 
3. Module #1 has to be imported by the Module #2

Comment: @Andrei, @ 
Anton Kochev It was working fine with Angular 8, but after upgrade it started giving error

Comment: yes. we understand. The reason that we've mentioned is the most probable one. So please check that modules declarations are correct

Comment: This was fixed by deleting my node_modules and package-lock.json and did npm install again, also i ran the angular update command again

Comment: @Anshul, that seems worth posting as an answer

Comment: @OutstandingBill It was causing issue because my node version was not correct, Due to some reason i switched to older version of node (12.14) and then i was doing npm install, so was getting the error. 

When i moved back to node version 14.15.0 and did fresh npm install after running rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json it worked for me

Comment: @Anshul, that sounds like the kind of situation anyone could run into.  It may not have been the OP's problem, but your fix might help someone else : )

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the component inside the module.

Comment: @user12923414 this was resolved, i had deleted my node_modules and package-lock.json and did npm install again